# Faster : drawing a rectangle or resizing a sprite?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two options and i want to know whats faster

I have a pool of 1000 sprites objects in as3 on screen

when its needed each sprite has to resize itself

I can

1 - make each sprite a simple container to use graphics to draw a rectangle, that is, call a `'spriteInstance.graphics.'` ,draw the rectangle and on each 'refresh', I do `graphics.clear` and redraw the rectangle but with the new size, this for each sprite.

or

2 - create each sprite with a border and on each refresh, resize it

whats better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, either way, you're creating a sprite for each rectangle, and what you've described is essentially the same thing so I doubt there will be any major performance enhancement there.

However, I believe that you could increase your performance by just having one sprite, holding the data of each 'sprite' in a vector, and then iterating through that vector, drawing each rectangle in the one sprite.

You might also want to look at [bitmap blitting (if you wanna keep each sprite individually) and double buffering](http://blog.ickydime.com/2008/05/blitting-and-double-buffering-with.html) for extra performance boost.

Comment: I need to create one sprite per object data, because I need to handle MouseEvents, I don't know if there is a lighter graphical element in as3 that handles mouse events.

any way, as you suggest, the performance hit isn't going to change much either war, so I believe I will keep with the simplest one